CS1237 ADC - series resistor of voltage reference too big?
I've recently tried multiple times to get consistent readings of a loadcell with a CS1237 ADC-module like the following:
https://www.androegg.de/shop/cs1237-24-bit-adc-ad-konverter-modul-tl431/
It uses a TL431 voltage reference, which I believe is configured to 2,5V (cathode and ref pins are shorted).
I constructed the loadcell myself by gluing 4 strain-gauges onto a steel piece, and with an HX711 it worked as expected.
With the CS1237 module, I only got gibberish (the communication between the ADC and the microcontroller works, though)
I've now tried to understand the working principle of the CS1237-module and found the series resistor to be too big:
My loadcell is made up of 350Ohms (bf350-3aa) strain gauges, so between it's excitation-pins it should also have a resistance of 350 Ohms and draw about (2,5V / 350 Ohms = ) 7,1mA. If my understanding of the TL431 is correct, it works like a 2,5V-Zener-Diode and I need to have a series resistor small enough, that my load still gets enough current.
Let's say the TL431 needs about 0,1mA to be in a defined state, so in total I need 7,2mA from my 3,3V VDD supply. Is my calculation correct that I need a series resistor of maximum (3,3V - 2,5V) / 7,2mA = 111 Ohms ? Currently on the module there's a 1kOhm resistor I believe (R1, SMD-Code 102)
The CS1237 is sometimes labeled as a drop-in replacement for the HX711. Therefore my two questions are:

Am I wrong and the 1kOhm resistor should work with my setup? and

Are there (commercial) loadcells which have a low enough resistance to work with a 1kOhm series resistor?


Kind regards,
Sepp

You are on the right track if your load is 350 ohm.
From the Texas Instruments TL431 Data Sheet:

You need a minimum of 0.7 mA to be safe, so you will need a resistor of (3,3V - 2,5V) / 7,8mA = 102 Ohms.  But you would also need to account for your lowest voltage instead of your nominal voltage of 3.3 volts, which will drop the resistance further.

I ended up trying a 100 Ohms first, which did work, but the output of the reference was not exactly stable at the specified 2.495 V. I'm now using a 56 Ohm resistor which works as expected, except for the fact that the ADC output drifts. But I'll have to open a separate question for that matter once I understood it a bit more... :) thanks
